# Normal Distribution Curve

Tags: regression, anova, normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics

I understand that if a graph is close to the shape of a bell shape (and the mean tends to zero, and the SD is close to 1), then we can say it is normally distributed. Visually inspecting a normal curve can be subjective as well. How should I confirm if the residuals of the curve below is normally or approximately normally distributed? I am using this judgment to as a pre-determination of ANOVA assumptions.

[image]

Comment: Can you give some context, why do you need an approximate normal distribution?  How to judge the approximation depends on purpose.

Comment: I am inspecting my data to ensure that they do not violate the assumptions for conducting an ANOVA and a Regression Analysis

Comment: "if a graph is close to the shape of a bell shape (and the mean tends to zero, and the SD is close to 1), then we can say it is normally distributed" -- (i) the mean and standard deviation are irrelevant to whether or not it's normally distributed; (ii) many things that are  very much *not* normal may look more or less bell-shaped, so merely looking bell shaped is not a means to assert normality; (iii) that doesn't look at all bell-shaped anyway; it's clearly bimodal. What's your response? (iv) are those residuals from the actual model you want to assess the assumptions of?

Comment: Consider trying to identify the two groups that seem to have accounted for two distributions here.  You might conduct a separate analysis on each group.

Comment: What do you mean by two groups? Why do you say it is bimodal? I see the term "conservative approach" is used. If the normality test says that the distribution is not normal, how should I proceed to conduct the ANOVA and Regression, apart from reporting that the sample is not normally distributed?

Comment: There can exist a factor variable you're missing that would divide the individuals in your histogram in two groups and in these groups, you would have a normal distribution (observe how your histogram does have 2 bell-shaped patterns, one centered at around -0.8 and the other 0.8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, visually inspecting is really subjective, but in your example, the histogram indicates two modes and the part with the most theoretical probability density (near 0) has too few points, so you have a strong "intuitive evidence" that a normal distribution assumption might not be appropriate.

Another (also subjective) form of inspecting normality is by looking at the [Q-Q Plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot). On the other hand, you can use a [Normality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test#Frequentist_tests) to decide if you consider the normality assumption is valid with only the significance level as a subjective factor.

Keep in mind that, as commented, you should understand and considerate the consequences of your normality assumption, like what parts of your analysis can be invalid because of it.